# Compile Mercurial

Tags: python, compiling, mercurial

I'm trying to install latest version of Mercurial (1.6.4) into my Ubuntu 10.10 but I'm getting this error when I do "make install":

Couldn't import standard zlib (incomplete Python install)

Worth knowing that I compiled and installed python 2.7 successfully, though, this error still appeared before installing 2.7. (Think Ubuntu 10.10 comes with 2.6)

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried this [post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mercurial)